# Condition for getting same numbers when multiplying each row and each column in an n * n grid

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A friend gave me an interesting problem recently that has me stumped:

How can I fill a 3 X 3 grid with the numbers 1, 2,...9 such that the three numbers obtained on multiplying each row, are the same three numbers we get on multiplying each column? What if I were to fill a 5 X 5 grid with the numbers 1,2,3...25? Is it possible to formulate a condition(s) that guarantee that it is possible/impossible to write the numbers 1,2,3....n^2 on an n x n grid such that the numbers obtained on multiplying each row and each column are the same?

I've gotten one solution to the 3 x 3 grid, but am struggling to generalize it or even just see if there are more than one combinations. The one I have now is given below:

5  ,  3  ,  8  =  120

6  ,  7  ,  1  =  42

4  ,  2  ,  9  =  72

And accordingly, multiplying each column will give 120, 42, 72 as well.

Comment: First of all, it is obvious that permuting rows or columns of a solution gives another solution.  Second, you can interchange $5$ and $7$ in the $3 \times 3$ grid and get another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that in an $n \times n$ grid, primes $> n^2/2$ can't share a row or column.  So a necessary condition for the $n \times n$ grid to be possible is that there are at most $n$ such primes.  That rules out $n \times n$ grids for $n=9$ and, I think, all $n \ge 11$.

Comment: Why does it rule out all n>=11?

Comment: It appears to me that for $n \ge 11$, there are more than $n$ primes between $n^2/2$ and $n^2$.  This should be provable using upper and lower bounds on $\pi(n^2)$ and $\pi(n^2/2)$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!